# Where can I share my Online Project to get some feedback?

Tags: website-review

Currently I'am developing a free online seo check tool script. 
But I need some feedback, I have seen sourceforge, 
but sourceforge is more for software and the site looks a little bit old to me.

I would like to have my own project page, 
where I can post the project url and all the information. (like a forum maybe?)

I know SitePoint.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search found [SiteCritic](http://www.sitecritic.net/).

Comment: thats not what Iam looking for. SiteCritic is for websites that are already finished. Iam looking for a WorkInProgress page.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Code](http://code.google.com/), [Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109440/best-git-repository-hosting-for-a-commercial-project), [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) and @JohnConde's SiteCritic all provide this service, sourceforge is old but also the most popular so far as I know.